# How to calculate threshold value in supervised principal component analysis?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

How to calculate the threshold value for selecting the number of features using supervised principal component analysis? I have a $152\times 27578$ data matrix  and I want to apply SPCA to reduce the matrix size.

Can any one tell me how to calculate that?

I got this paper but I am unable to understand how they are calculating $\theta$ value (threshold value): [Bair et al. 2004, Prediction by supervised principal components](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ftp/spca.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea of the "supervised principal component analysis" is described on page 5 of the paper you are reading:

> Supervised principal components
>
> 1. Compute (univariate) standard regression coefficients for each feature
> 2. Form a reduced data matrix consisting of only those features whose univariate
>      coefficient exceeds a threshold $\theta$ in absolute value **($\theta$ is estimated
>      by cross-validation)**
> 3. Compute the first (or first few) principal components of the reduced data
>      matrix
> 4. Use these principal component(s) in a regression model to predict the
>      outcome

I selected with bold font the answer to your question. The threshold value is not "calculated"; it is selected using cross-validation, i.e. one selects the value of $\theta$ that gives the best performance.

(It is not clear from your question if you have a dependent variable in addition to your $152\times 27578$ data matrix. SPCA can only be applied if you have one.)

Comment: I wanted to know from what they are calculating the cross-validation .To take the theta value are they choosing different value of theta and then from that they are choosing the best one .?

Comment: Are you familiar with cross-validation? You split your dataset in training and test parts, then for each value of theta you fit the model on the training part and use it to predict the test part. Then you see what theta yields the best performance on a test set (averaged over different train-test splits). I am still not sure if you have a dependent variable, but I assume that you do.

Comment: I am familiar with cross validation. But as per the paper  from the data sets   I got the score for each feature [27578 scores] from that scores I need to select the the top features. Here theta helps me to select only those features that gives me maximum prediction from my further classification .My question is here are they selecting theta as [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9] from that whatever features they are getting are they cross validating and taking the best theta value.

Comment: Not sure if I completely get your question, but you are supposed to cross-validate *your whole procedure* which includes applying the theta threshold, then doing PCA on the remaining features, and then selecting one or several PCs. So yes, for example for each theta in  [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9] you do *all of that* in a cross-validation loop, and then for each theta you will get some resulting prediction error.

Comment: you mean to say first I need to choose the different value of theta and then from that newly obtained data matrices. should I cross validate for all the different data matrix. From that I choose the best data matrix with best cross validation error.

Comment: No, there is some confusion here. For each value of theta you do feature selection and then PCA, and then compute the prediction error on the test data. After cross-validation is finished, you will have one value of error for each value of theta. Select the theta that gives the lowest error. After that you can apply this theta to build your prediction model with all available data (and "to reduce the matrix size" if that is what you are after).

Comment: Does it make sense, @vinay?

Comment: yes I am implementing that. you have the point

Comment: I see, let me know if it worked! By the way, if you find an answer (any answer) useful, please don't forget to upvote it; I am only saying it because I can see that you have 0 votes ever cast so perhaps you are unaware of this feature. And of course if any post answers your question, don't forget to accept it (but I can see that you have some accepted answers already so you should know how it works). Good luck.

Comment: Hey, @vinay, I am curious - did it work out in the end?

Comment: It worked for me but I am not getting results as expected for my research work. I am implementing more along with that

Comment: I was just trying to understand if you consider your question answered or not :-) If yes, consider accepting my answer. If not, consider updating / clarifying your question to indicate what remains unclear.